# Sometimes FCKeditor doesn't load in Firefox

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I am unable to replicate the problem when I want to but it seems like every now and then, my site using FCKeditor will load the interface but not the content (Clicking the buttons don't do anything). No javascript errors show and once it starts doing it, it usually is tough to get back to normal. The way I found to work best is to click the refresh button multiple times in a row, then the FCKeditor loads correctly. I have only seen this in Firefox

Has anyone else run into this problem or know a solution. It is a little annoying for me but I am afraid my client would be really confused

Comment: seems like cache problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem.  I solved it by pre-loading FCKeditor in a hidden iframe during the login process so that when it got to the pages where it was used it was already in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the phenomenon you describe in FCKEditor's successor, CKEditor. Somehow, the IFRAME that contains the WYSIWYG content doesn't get loaded. What always helps is switching to source code view and back, but that's no solution.

I have seen the problem described on the Internet but with no solution.

Caching is not the problem, I think. Sometimes, if you press "reload" 20 times, it will break at the 21th time, and work again on the 22nd time.

What minimized the number of occurrences for me was to activate the thingy to the editor's bottom that shows the element path (body > p > span, I forgot it's name). I don't now why but since I turned it on, it very rarely breaks any more.

Answer (score 1):

i would strongly advise to upgrade to [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) which can not only be spelled out verbally without offending anyone, but also optimizes the loading time to minimal. I find it much more responsive than his F- friend.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem with firefox (not reproducible) and chrome (reproducible).
The solution that worked quite well in both cases was to wait for some milliseconds before initializing CKE :

```
setTimeout(function() {textarea.ckeditor({customConfig : 'custom/schnonfig.js'})} , 100);
```